# Did anything major change that my Cloud functions stopped working with flutter web?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I used to have Firebase Cloud Functions running. But after refactoring my whole codebase to sound null safety, cloud functions stopped working (Sadly, I cannot reproduce at which point in the timeline)..

pubspec.yaml

```
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      firebase_core: ^1.0.2
      firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
      cloud_firestore: ^1.0.4
      cloud_functions: ^1.1.0
      ...
```

web/index.html

```html
...
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    
  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "<myApiKey>",
      authDomain: "<my-project>.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://<my-project>.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "<my-project>",
      storageBucket: "<my-project>.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "<myMessageSenderId>",
      appId: "<myAppId>"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://10.0.2.2:5001");
  </script>
  
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

functions/index.js

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { UserPropertyValue } = require('firebase-functions/lib/providers/analytics');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.setRoles = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let userId = null;
    let userCustomClaimsAdmin = false;
    let userCustomClaimsEditor = false;

    // get user and update custom claim
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {

        userId = user.uid;
        const currentCustomClaims = (user.customClaims == undefined) ? {} : user.customClaims;
        switch (data.role) {
            case 'admin':
                currentCustomClaims.admin = (data.permission == 'grant') ? true : false;
            break;
            case 'editor':
                currentCustomClaims.editor = (data.permission == 'grant') ? true : false;
            break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        userCustomClaimsAdmin = currentCustomClaims.admin;
        userCustomClaimsEditor = currentCustomClaims.editor;

        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId,
            currentCustomClaims
        );
        }).then(() => {
            // Update User record in Firestore
            return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).update({
                isAdmin: userCustomClaimsAdmin,
                isEditor: userCustomClaimsEditor,
            });
        }).then(() => {
            return {
                message: 'Success'
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.toString());
        });
});
```

Finally I call the function with:

```dart
...
   final HttpsCallable setRoleCallable = FirebaseFunctions.instance
        .httpsCallable('setRoles',
            options:
                HttpsCallableOptions(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10)));
...
              try {
                final HttpsCallableResult result = await setRoleCallable.call(
                  <String, dynamic>{
                    'email': "<emailOfUserToBeChanged>",
                    'role': "<selectedRole>",
                    'permission': "<givenAccess>"
                  },
                );
                print(result.data);
              } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
                print('caught firebase functions exception');
                print(e.code);
                print(e.message);
                print(e.details);
              } catch (e) {
                print('caught generic exception');
                print(e);
              }
```

That call (emulated functions at localhost resp. 10.0.2.2) ends in

```
caught firebase functions exception
internal
internal
null
```

Did anything change in the meantime that I have missed? I could not find anything regarding this topic within the Firebase documentation.

Perhaps it might be a little change at some point that I did not recognize yet..

Answer (score 1):

Well, a major change with Cloud Functions is that you now **have to have the paid Firebase plan** to use cloud functions as they sadly **removed Cloud Functions from the free tier**.

Comment: Thanks, that hint might be useful for future readers. In my case I use Blaze-Plan for the project :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Cloud Function you don't wait for the asynchronous operations to complete before sending back the response. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details on this key aspect.

The tricky thing is that it generates some "erratic" behaviour (sometimes it works, sometimes not) that can be explained as follows:

- In some cases, your Cloud Function is terminated before the asynchronous operations are completed, as explained in the doc referred to above.
- But, in some other cases, it may be possible that the Cloud Functions platform does not immediately terminate your CF, giving enough time for the asynchronous operations to be completed.

So you have the impression that "Cloud functions stopped working with flutter web" while, actually, sometimes it works and some other times not...

---

In addition, note that the `setCustomUserClaims()` method returns a `Promise<void>` not a `user`, therefore you need to keep a set of global variables for the userId and the claims in order to pass it from one `then()` block to the other.

---

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.setRoles = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log('user to change email: ' + data.email);

    let userId = null;
    let userCustomClaimsAdmin = false;
    let userCustomClaimsEditor = false;

    // get user and update custom claim
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email)
        .then(user => {

            userId = user.uid;   //  the setCustomUserClaims() method returns a Promise<void> not a user !!

            const currentCustomClaims = (user.customClaims == undefined) ? {} : user.customClaims;
            switch (data.role) {
                case 'admin':
                    currentCustomClaims.admin = (data.permission == 'grant') ? true : false;
                    break;
                case 'editor':
                    currentCustomClaims.editor = (data.permission == 'grant') ? true : false;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
                    break;
            }

            // Here you need to adapt the value of userCustomClaimsAdmin and userCustomClaimsEditor
            userCustomClaimsAdmin = ...
            userCustomClaimsEditor = ...

            // See return below !!!!
         
            return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid,
                currentCustomClaims
            );

        })
        .then(() => {
            // See return below  !!!!
            return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).update({
                isAdmin: (userCustomClaimsAdmin) ? user.customClaims.admin : false,
                isEditor: (userCustomClaimsEditor) ? user.customClaims.editor : false,
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
            return {
                message: 'Success'
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.toString());
            // !!!! See the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will change the code accordingly and post the result later...

Comment: Well, I changed the index.js (updated this post as well) but the error/result remains the same.

Comment: You need to adapt the part `//Here you need to adapt the value...`

Comment: I thought, I did?! I set the global variables with the values of currentCustomClaims. Otherwise I am quite helpless here. What do you mean? Perhaps I just did not get it right..

Comment: You should debug the code with some [logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs).

Comment: I am afraid that the problem could be somewhere else. Even if I log as first action, I will get the internal error :(
```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { UserPropertyValue } = require('firebase-functions/lib/providers/analytics');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.setRoles = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    functions.logger.log("Hello from info. Here's the user's email:", data.email);
...
```
Is there a proper way to update everything to latest version? Maybe I missed anything here?

Comment: Can you give more details about that error? Seems to be just part of your code.

Comment: Even if I simply use a "Hello World" function it will result in the given error. I cannot figure out, where the problem might be.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am developing a flutter-web project. I use cloud-functions, not cloud-functions-web.

In my main.dart the directive to use the functions emulator was missing:

```dart
...
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseFunctions.instance
      .useFunctionsEmulator(origin: 'http://localhost:5001'); // this was missing
  runApp(MyApp());
...
}
```

It used to work, as I already had that directive in my index.html

```js
...
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://10.0.2.2:5001");
...
```

Nevertheless it works now.